# LFS:gcc compile error: fatal error: string.h: No such file or directory

Tags: gcc

I'm trying to work my way through [Linux From Scratch](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/view/stable/index.html). I am running into the compiler:

> error : string.h: No such file or directory

when trying to compile gcc for the target system as per [Chapter 5: gcc-4.8.1-pass 1](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/view/stable/chapter05/gcc-pass1.html).

More details about the error:

> -fexceptions -fnon-call-exceptions -fvisibility=hidden -DHIDE_EXPORTS
>       /mnt/lfs/sources/gcc-build/./gcc/xgcc -B/mnt/lfs/sources/gcc-build/./gcc/ 
>       -B/tools    /x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu/bin/ -B/tools/x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu/lib/ 
>       -isystem /tools/x86_64- lfs-linux-gnu/include 
>       -isystem /tools/x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu/sys-include -g -O2 -O2  -g -O2 -DIN_GCC 
>       -DCROSS_DIRECTORY_STRUCTURE  -W -Wall -Wno-narrowing -Wwrite-strings -Wcast-qual
>       -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-prototypes -Wold-style-definition  -isystem ./include
>        -fpic -mlong-double-80 -g -DIN_LIBGCC2 -fbuilding-libgcc -fno-stack-protector 
>        -Dinhibit_libc  -fpic -mlong-double-80 -I. -I. -I../.././gcc -I../../../gcc-4.8.1/libgcc 
>       -I../../../gcc-4.8.1/libgcc/. 
>       -I../../../gcc-4.8.1/libgcc/../gcc -I../../../gcc-4.8.1/libgcc/../include -I../../../gcc-4.8.1/libgcc/../libdecnumber/no -I../../../gcc-4.8.1/libgcc/../libdecnumber -DHAVE_CC_TLS  -DUSE_TLS -o decContext.o 
>       -MT decContext.o -MD -MP -MF decContext.dep -c ../../../gcc-4.8.1/libgcc/../libdecnumber/decContext.c
>       ../../../gcc-4.8.1/libgcc/../libdecnumber/decContext.c:33:43: fatal error: string.h: No such file or directory
>    #include        /* for strcmp */
>                                              ^
>       compilation terminated.
>       make[2]:*  [decContext.o] Error 1
>       make[2]: Leaving directory `/mnt/lfs/sources/gcc-build/x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu/libgcc'
>       make[1]: *** [all-target-libgcc] Error 2
>       make[1]: Leaving directory`/mnt/lfs/sources/gcc-build'
>       make: * [all] Error 2

Additional information that might be of use:

1. I am running ubuntu linux with gcc 4.8.1
2. I have installed the build-essential package and it is the most recent version
3. The file string.h *is* present

Thanks in advance for any help.

This is the code I am running:

```
../gcc-4.8.1/configure                               \
    --target=$LFS_TGT                                \
    --prefix=/tools                                  \
    --with-sysroot=$LFS                              \
    --with-newlib                                    \
    --without-headers                                \
    --with-local-prefix=/tools                       \
    --with-native-system-header-dir=/tools/include   \
    --disable-nls                                    \
    --disable-shared                                 \
    --disable-multilib                               \
    --disable-decimal-float                          \
    --disable-threads                                \
    --disable-libatomic                              \
    --disable-libgomp                                \
    --disable-libitm                                 \
    --disable-libmudflap                             \
    --disable-libquadmath                            \
    --disable-libsanitizer                           \
    --disable-libssp                                 \
    --disable-libstdc++-v3                           \
    --enable-languages=c,c++                         \
    --with-mpfr-include=$(pwd)/../gcc-4.8.1/mpfr/src \
    --with-mpfr-lib=$(pwd)/mpfr/src/.libs
```

then it breaks on `make`. I am executing this command from `$LFS/sources/gcc-build`. `gcc-4.8.1` is located in `$LFS/sources`.

Comment: I added the code above.

Comment: Create a file `foo.c` containing just one line `#include <string.h>`, then compile it with `gcc -c foo.c`. Do you get the same error?

Comment: That works... I did manage destroy my system earlier today (or more accurately KDE plasma did) so I am working with a fresh install. I need to do a little work to get things up and running again with respect to LFS, then I'll try compiling gcc again.